# How do I use a Hibernate entity-interceptor with JPA transaction manager?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am converting over XML-based config from a Spring app. This is what a section of the config looks like in XML:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <!--<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop> -->
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="net.vivin" />
</bean>

<bean id="timeStampedEntityInterceptor" class="net.vivin.myapp.hibernate.interceptor.TimeStampedEntityInterceptor" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
      p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory"
      p:entityInterceptor-ref="timeStampedEntityInterceptor">
</bean>
```

After looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337504/hibernatetransactionmanager-or-jpatransactionmanager), I can see that the best practice is to use the JPA transaction manager instead of Hibernate's transaction manager.

What I can't figure out is how to set an entity interceptor on the JPA transaction manager. Does anyone know how this can be done? An XML-based config is fine too because I can convert that over to Java. In my Java config, for the transaction manager all I have is:

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    return jpaTransactionManager;
}
```

However, the `JpaTransactionManager` has no method to set an interceptor. Does anyone know how this can be done? Or will I simply have to use Hibernate's transaction manager?

Comment: @Amogh Yes. My solution was to forgo the hibernate interceptor entirely and convert it over to JPA listener. It's a little cleaner this way too.

Answer (score 3):

You can use one of the following [Hibernate properties](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/configuration.html) (in persistence.xml or supply them into the JPATransactionManager):

- hibernate.ejb.interceptor : this interceptor will be shared by all Sessions, making this interceptor SessionFactory scope bound.
- hibernate.ejb.interceptor.session_scoped : a new instance will be supplied to every Session, making this interceptor Session scope bound.

Answer (score 3):

As it turns out, I was going about this completely wrong. The solution wasn't to try and use a Hibernate entity-interceptor with my code. I opted to use a JPA listener instead, and used the `@EntityListeners` annotation on my entity. This essentially has the same functionality as an interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an EntityInterceptor in your LocalSessionFactoryBean definition. The LocalSessionFactoryBean is Hibernate-specific.