# How to add mysql datasource to applicationContext.xml

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, maven

I am making a dynamic web application.
In my application I use Spring and Hibernate.

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>rasika.gayan.nought</groupId>
<artifactId>mit-site-temp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<!-- spring framework spring framework spring framework -->

<!-- Shared version number properties -->
<properties>
    <org.springframework.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Core utilities used by other modules. Define this if you use Spring 
        Utility APIs (org.springframework.core.*/org.springframework.util.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Expression Language (depends on spring-core) Define this if you use 
        Spring Expression APIs (org.springframework.expression.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Bean Factory and JavaBeans utilities (depends on spring-core) Define 
        this if you use Spring Bean APIs (org.springframework.beans.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) Framework (depends on spring-core, 
        spring-beans) Define this if you use Spring AOP APIs (org.springframework.aop.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Application Context (depends on spring-core, spring-expression, spring-aop, 
        spring-beans) This is the central artifact for Spring's Dependency Injection 
        Container and is generally always defined -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Various Application Context utilities, including EhCache, JavaMail, 
        Quartz, and Freemarker integration Define this if you need any of these integrations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Transaction Management Abstraction (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
        spring-aop, spring-context) Define this if you use Spring Transactions or 
        DAO Exception Hierarchy (org.springframework.transaction.*/org.springframework.dao.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JDBC Data Access Library (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, 
        spring-tx) Define this if you use Spring's JdbcTemplate API (org.springframework.jdbc.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Object-to-Relation-Mapping (ORM) integration with Hibernate, JPA, 
        and iBatis. (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-tx) 
        Define this if you need ORM (org.springframework.orm.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Object-to-XML Mapping (OXM) abstraction and integration with JAXB, 
        JiBX, Castor, XStream, and XML Beans. (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
        spring-context) Define this if you need OXM (org.springframework.oxm.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Web application development utilities applicable to both Servlet and 
        Portlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context) 
        Define this if you use Spring MVC, or wish to use Struts, JSF, or another 
        web framework with Spring (org.springframework.web.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring MVC for Servlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
        spring-context, spring-web) Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Servlet 
        Container such as Apache Tomcat (org.springframework.web.servlet.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring MVC for Portlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
        spring-context, spring-web) Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Portlet 
        Container (org.springframework.web.portlet.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Support for testing Spring applications with tools such as JUnit and 
        TestNG This artifact is generally always defined with a 'test' scope for 
        the integration testing framework and unit testing stubs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- javax servlet -->

     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- javax servlet jsp -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- hibernate -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- spring data jpa -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- jdbc driver -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- slf4j -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<!-- jetty and compiler -->

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.3.v20140905</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

in my pom.xml I include **org.hibernate.javax.persistence** and **javax.persistence** **.
Is that correct????**

Then here is my applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">


<!-- this will scan other all in directory -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.rasika.gayan">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"
        expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan>

<!-- ***************jpa configeration ********************** -->

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    id="transactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/finalyearproject" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="r00t" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.xxx.yyy.entity.Complains</value>
            <value>com.xxx.yyy.entity.LogFileContent</value>
            <value>com.xxx.yyy.entity.OrderDetail</value>
            <value>com.xxx.yyy.entity.SendDeliverableDetail</value>
            <value>com.xxx.yyy.entity.SkillDetail</value>
            <value>com.xxx.yyy.entity.TaskDetail</value>
            <value>com.xxx.yyy.entity.TaskRateDetail</value>
            <value>com.xxx.yyy.entity.TempUser</value>
            <value>com.xxx.yyy.entity.UserComments</value>
            <value>com.xxx.yyy.entity.UserDetail</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>




<!-- **org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource -->
<!-- org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource -->
```

after I build my application I got his error.........................................

```
        SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
        SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
        SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
        [INFO] Scanning for projects...
        [INFO]                                                                         
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [INFO] Building mit-site-temp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [INFO] 
        [INFO] >>> jetty-maven-plugin:9.2.3.v20140905:run (default-cli) @ mit-site-temp >>>
        [INFO] 
        [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ mit-site-temp ---
        [debug] execute contextualize
        [WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
        [INFO] Copying 0 resource
        [INFO] 
        [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) @ mit-site-temp ---
        [WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.9 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
        [WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.9 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
        [WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.9 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
        [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
        [INFO] 
        [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ mit-site-temp ---
        [debug] execute contextualize
        [WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
        [INFO] Copying 0 resource
        [INFO] 
        [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ mit-site-temp ---
        [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
        [INFO] 
        [INFO] <<< jetty-maven-plugin:9.2.3.v20140905:run (default-cli) @ mit-site-temp <<<
        [INFO] 
        [INFO] --- jetty-maven-plugin:9.2.3.v20140905:run (default-cli) @ mit-site-temp ---
        2014-10-24 20:55:54.158:INFO::main: Logging initialized @3946ms
        [INFO] Configuring Jetty for project: mit-site-temp
        [INFO] webAppSourceDirectory not set. Trying src\main\webapp
        [INFO] Reload Mechanic: automatic
        [INFO] Classes = D:\MITSite\target\classes
        [INFO] Context path = /
        [INFO] Tmp directory = D:\MITSite\target\tmp
        [INFO] Web defaults = org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
        [INFO] Web overrides =  none
        [INFO] web.xml file = file:/D:/MITSite/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
        [INFO] Webapp directory = D:\MITSite\src\main\webapp
        2014-10-24 20:55:54.230:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.3.v20140905
        2014-10-24 20:55:58.044:INFO:/:main: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
        2014-10-24 20:55:58.096:INFO:/:main: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
        log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
        log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
        log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
        2014-10-24 20:55:58.503:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@4857e34a{/,file:/D:/MITSite/src/main/webapp/,STARTING}{file:/D:/MITSite/src/main/webapp/}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined

    ////// minimize the error log ................

    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
    Caused by: 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined

    ////// minimize the error log .......

    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
    2014-10-24 20:55:58.508:WARN:oejsh.RequestLogHandler:main: !RequestLog
    2014-10-24 20:55:58.526:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED ServerConnector@45c01e6{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind


////// minimize the error log.......

    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
    2014-10-24 20:55:58.526:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.MavenServerConnector@3480a546: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind

///// minimize the error log..........
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
2014-10-24 20:55:58.526:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyServer@26ed15da: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind

///// at last in error log

[INFO] Jetty server exiting.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.172s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Oct 24 20:55:58 IST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 31M/260M

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.2.3.v20140905:run (default-cli) on project mit-site-temp: Failure: Address already in use: bind -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

**Can please help me on this ???**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you've 2 problem here :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined
```

Which in other words means that you can't use an hibernate session factory with JPA TransactionManager, you will have to choose between a simple `Spring + hibernate` approach (spring transaction management + hibernate session factory, [see outdated exemple here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-hibernate-mysql-example/)) or 
a `Spring + JPAAdapter + JPA` (spring JPA transaction management + JPA entityManagerFactory

To understand the difference between the 2 approaches see [HibernateTransactionManager or JpaTransactionManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337504/hibernatetransactionmanager-or-jpatransactionmanager)

The second problem

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
```

means the server expected listened http port is already used by another program (use `TCPView` to know which one)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are mising dependencies. If you are a new to Java, please try to read the error messages, that will help you a lot. Just google "Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"", you will find many realted posts. You need to add commons logging dependencies in pom.xml. Aslo, the Title of the question is not relevant. You are actually having build issues, datasource would be the next step. Hope this helps.

EDIT : 
Sample dependency. I will still recommend to check the link in comment to understand it better.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Bean "transactionManager" definition :

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Comment: but in pom.xml I add "org.slf4j" dependancy.

Comment: Please check this link : http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html If you dont have time look at http://www.javavids.com/video/logging-using-slf4j-log4j-in-maven-application.html I think you also need logger properties.

Comment: Looks like the problem is with bean "transactionManager". You are defining property "dataSource" but I think you need to define "entityManagerFactory". I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/YOUR_DATABASE_NAME" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="123456" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.Dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.autodll">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.deneme</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```