# Switched from Hibernate 4.3.11 to 5.0.2 and suddenly TransactionRequiredException

Tags: spring, hibernate, entitymanager, spring-orm

I have upgraded to `hibernate-core` and `hibernate-entitymanager` from 4.3.11 to 5.0.2 and suddenly all what has functioned smoothly, now throws the following exception.

> javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'merge' call
>   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityMa
>   nagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:277)
>
> ...

The same happens not only for `merge` operation of the instance of `EntityManager` but for `persist` as well.

I have googled a little bit and all what I could find was only about missing `@Transactional` annotation which all my DAOs are annotated with. Anyway with with the previous version it worked like a charm.

Has anybody experienced the same problem with the newest version of Hibernate?

**EDIT**: based on comments

I want to be independent of a concrete JPA implementation and want to use JPA's `EntityManager` instead of Hibernate's `SessionFactory`. Exactly like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337504/hibernatetransactionmanager-or-jpatransactionmanager) question.

Comment: I am not 100% sure but normally spring was providing support for Hibernate4 and you use most likely     "org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager". It may related to not providing support by spring for hibernate5.

Comment: I do not use this subpackage. What I do use is `import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter`, so this seems not to be the problem.

Comment: what do you use as the transaction manager

Comment: Which Spring version do you use exactly?

Comment: @dunni I use 4.2.1.FINAL.

Comment: @cool I use `JpaTransactionManager`.

Comment: @cool Using `HibernateTransactionManager` forces me to use `SessionFactory` interface (implementation `org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean` instead of `org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` for `JpaTransactionManager`. I want to keep using `org.springframework.orm.jpa.*` instead of tightly tying my code to a specific Hibernate version.

Comment: I am also getting same excpetion, I am using hibernate 4.2.21.Final. But i got this exception when i upgrade my spring version from 4.1.6 to 4.2.3.Release

Comment: @SathishMurugesan Hi, I have solved this problem by completely refactoring my code and switching to Spring JPA Repositories.

Comment: @SathishMurugesan Did you check if you have a transactionSynchronization set to 2 (SYNCHRONIZATION_NEVER) somewhere on the JpaTransactionManager definition?

Comment: No, I didnt set anything like that.. Till Spring Version 4.1.6.Release, it worked like charm without any issue but now it doesnt work. Moreover exception was thrown at debug level. If i put back to 4.1.6 it works fine without any issues.

Comment: @Yosh. I checked i gave it all options Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, Propagation.REQUIRED etc.., Nothing helps. I always getting same exception. But when i switch back to old version it works like a charm