# JpaTransactionManager + HibernateTransactionManager in one app

Tags: spring, hibernate

Is it possible to have both JpaTransactionManager and HibernateTransactionManager in one Spring MVC application?  This code looks like was getting session factory from entityManagerFactory. Is it one or the other or can you actually have two?

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="spring-jpa" />
</bean>

**<bean id="sessionFactory" factory-bean="entityManagerFactory" factory-method="getSessionFactory" />**

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have only one transaction manager. The JPATransactionManager doesn't tie you to the JPA implementation, in this case Hibernate. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337504/hibernatetransactionmanager-or-jpatransactionmanager) out.